# How do I solve "No OpenCL runtime lib" in Wine on Linux

Tags: linux, emulation, wine

I am trying to move to linux, but to be able to move I absolutely must have Cinema 4D installed and runnning. I cant use a full VM cause I dont have a second GPU to passthrough.
Ive been fiddling with wine all day, different installers etc. First I tried just wine+winetweaks through terminal manually, but I couldnt get any  output. Then I tried PlayonLinux, which got me somewhere, but I it seems it cant connect to the internet cause when I try to sign in it just makes me try again:
[image: cant sign in]

Next try was a repo called "bottles", which got the furthest and actually installed and opened the app (Though an older, cracked version to see if the old license manager could open it. I only have a license for the new manager though, so it wouldnt help me cause I prefer to not pirate.

[image: C4D opencl missing]

after spending a day on trying I am at a loss. Ive seen people manage it before, so I hope theres someone out there who could help me! I was using the latest wine avaiable today. Distro : Garuda linux, arch based I think.
Thanks in advance, djkáťo.

Comment: Ensure you have the 32-bit OpenCL libraries installed. Also try with a different runner in Bottles.